# How can I restore disable_functions locally with PHP-FPM?

Tags: php, security, nginx, fpm

I host multiple low-to-none traffic websites on a single Nginx+PHP-FPM 7.4 server. Due to security concern, I [disable_functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) in my php.ini, like so:

```
disable_functions = exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen
```

Now one of these website needs `proc_open`, so I'm trying to restore the function just for this one website via `php.ini`:

```
[PATH=/var/www/my-website]
disable_functions = mao,bao
```

`phpinfo()` reports a `Local value` consistent with my config

[image]

But even if it looks OK, it doesn't really work and I still get

> The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation

So, the question is: **is there any way to restore disable_functions for just this one website?**

---

The only clue I can find in the phpdoc is:

> This directive must be set in php.ini For example, you cannot set this in httpd.conf

Maybe the `[PATH=...]` syntax I used is the same?

Comment: _"Maybe the [PATH=...] syntax I used is the same?"_ - where exactly did you find that? I have never seen that in the context of a PHP ini file, and can't find anything about this in the documentation either.

Comment: I put it in the `php.ini` file. It's the FPM way to set the PHP parameters for certain path only.

Comment: Not sure if this applies here, but https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php says, _"Please note that defining disable_functions or disable_classes will not overwrite previously defined php.ini values, but will append the new value instead."_ (But I can't tell if that applies to trying to set them via php_value or php_flag only, or in general.)

Comment: Can't you configure that one specific site to use a separate `php.ini` of its own in this environment?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should have a different [PHP-FPM pool](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php) for those site with a different php.ini and the disabled functions enabled. The php-fpm process support a `-c` option to specify directory to look for `php.ini`. You may start a different `php-fpm` pool with that option.

If you don't want to mess with multiple `php.ini`, an easier way is to remove the desired function from `disable_functions` and add it back with `php_value` to your normal php-fpm pool. Then all you need to do for the new pool is to not have that `php_value`.

The pool can listen on a different port / unix socket. Then configure Nginxfor the one / multiple special site(s) with `fastcgi_pass` to use the different port / unix socket.